# Trying to visualize the time domain of a sound with Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio

I have a problem trying to visualize the time domain of a sound. I can play the sound well - it works. but when I connect the analyzer node to the sound source (which is well connected because the song plays) and to the context.destination,`getByteTimeDomainData` returns the value 128, which means no signal. Is there any additional connection I should make? 
that part of code, when I connect the analyzer looks like this:

```
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
soundSource.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
```

More code (from the comment below):

```
source = context.createBufferSource();
source.buffer = audioBuffer;
source.loop = false;
var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);
analyser.fftSize = 2048;
var timeDomain = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeDomain);
```

Comment: pls share more code, on first look its ok, may be you have to add fftsize to your analser.

Comment: `source = context.createBufferSource();
  source.buffer = audioBuffer;
  source.loop = false;
  
 
    var analyser = context.createAnalyser();
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination); analyser.fftSize = 2048;
   
     var timeDomain = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
  analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(timeDomain);`

Comment: I'm not really sure that I'm on the right track, but at the end I want to display the waveform of the sound. I'm a beginner in signal processing...maybe you can help me

Comment: Boy, this is depressing